# How to type text on hidden text box in WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, javascript, input, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

I am trying to sendkeys to an input，but I don't know why it warns me like this:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

The HTML page source:

```
<span id="mini-7" class="mini-textbox mini-textbox-empty" style="border-width: 0pt; width: 342px;">
<input class="mini-textbox-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 338px;">
<input type="hidden">
</span>
```

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mini-7 > input.mini-textbox-input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mini-7 > input.mini-textbox-input")).sendKeys("yy");
```

Then I change my code like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
((JavascriptExecutor) jse).executeScript("arguments[0].type ='text';",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='mini-7']/input[2]")));
```

But this time it throws out js error. Why?

I use sendkeys to the first input，this input is not hidden

Comment: did you try with capitalized "HIDDEN" ? IE has some issues

Comment: I fixed it ，just like this：JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       ((JavascriptExecutor) jse).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='mini-7']/input")));      
but i still donot know why

Comment: What language did you use? Java? C#? or what?

Answer (score 1):

That input could still have css property `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`. That's what exception is telling you. Check all the properties with browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it needs to change the value of type attribute as text from hidden. Now, you are able to type on that text by using WebDriver. So, the overall code for typing with WebDriver using Java and Javascript as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('mini-7').setAttribute('type', 'text');");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mini-7 > input.mini-textbox-input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mini-7 > input.mini-textbox-input")).sendKeys("yy");
```

For 1st input field which is not hidden, use absolute path for cssSelector.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful for me

Comment: Using Relative path for xpath is recommended than Absolute path. But unfortunately sometimes Relative path doesn't work, in that case way is to use Absolute path

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case is making the element visible by modifying the css tag for

```
visibility: hidden
```

or

```
display: none
```

using javascript just before sending keys to it.